# Angular2 SharedService passing ID as default but can be changed

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a `sharedService()` to get all the items in a particular location, I have put a default ID value of `3` but I want to have a dropdown menu where they can change a location `Id: 4, Id: 5`.

```
private sourceSiteId = 3;
getOriginSite() {
    return this.http.get('http://www.example.com/api/Orders?sourceSite=' + this.sourceSiteId)
      .map(res =>res.json());
  }
```

then I call this `sharedService` in my component to get the items and output it using `*ngFor`, when a user change location it should also update the list of items base on the chosen location.

**Edit: I put the wrong function, it should be this one which is also being called in `ngOnInit()`**

```
getOrdersFromOrigin() {
  this.sharedService.getOriginSite()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.items= data.Results
 }
```

item lists `ngFor` which needs to be updated when selecting a location. This is the order list html which has the nav as

```
<nav></nav>
<div *ngFor="let x of items"> 
 <button>{{ x.name }}</button>
</div>
```

At the moment I've only created a dummy locations which to get the logic. This is from the nav component which is a child component in the order list html.

```
this.sourceSites = [
  {
    'Id': 1,
    'StoreLocation': 'Eastleigh'
  },
  {
    'Id': 2,
    'StoreLocation': 'Portchester'
  },
  {
    'Id': 3,
    'StoreLocation': 'Soho'
  },
  {
    'Id': 4,
    'StoreLocation': 'Basingstoke'
  }
]

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li *ngFor="let store of sourceSites"><a href="javascript:;" (click)="changeSite(store.Id);">{{ store.StoreLocation}}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**Update**
This is what I have, I pass the location ID in my click function which then I pass to the service. But this doesn't have the default value of `3` because `getOrderById()` is being triggered in `ngOnInit`, so the initial API call will then be `null`

This is in my ChildComponent 
    changeSite(sourceSite) {
        this.sharedService.getOriginSite(sourceSite)
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data); // gives me the data I want to render in the parent ngFor
          })
      }

SharedService

```
getOriginSite(sourceSite) {
    return this.http.get('http://myexample.com/api/Orders?sourceSite='+ sourceSite)
      .map(res =>res.json());
  }
```

How can I change the `sourceSite=3` value to a chosen location and update the list once location is chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different solutions for your problem, depending on how you structured your app.

Lets say your dropdown is a child component and the parent is the one calling the service.

On your dropdown you create an `Output()` that emits an event when the value changes/user clicks.

Something like:

```
 public idChanged: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

 //Click handler
 public optionClicked(id: number): void {
   this.idChanged.emit(id);
 }
```

Then the parent component subscribes to that output like this:

```
 <dropdown (idChanged)="changeId($event)"></dropdown>
```

And on the parent class we create the `changeId()` method and call the service to update the list with the new ID.

```
 public changeId(id: number): void {
   //Call service with the new Id.
 }
```

Another solution would be storing the ID in the service, and every time the ID changes in the dropdown, update the service directly with the ID.

Comment: I've updated my post, I'm passing the `Id` in the `changeSite(id)` which is then pass back to the `SharedService` which gives me the objects I want to render in the parent html, which is where I get stuck how to pass this objs to the parent. I will try the first solution.